# Can we declare a partial specialization of a template class member after instantiation of the enclosing class template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer

Let's consider this simple exemple:

```
template<class T>
struct A{
  template<class V,class=void>
  struct B{
    static const int value=1 ;
  };
};

#ifdef PRE_INSTANTIATION
A<int> a;
#endif

#ifdef PARTIAL_SPECIALIZATION_OF_TEMPLATE_MEMBER
template<class T>
template<class V>
struct A<T>::B<double,V>{
  static const int value = 2;
};
#else //PARTIAL_SPECIALIZATION_OF_SPECIALIZATION_MEMBER
template<>
template<class V>
struct A<int>::B<double,V>{
  static const int value = 2;
};
#endif

static_assert(A<int>::B<int>::value==1,"");
#if __clang__ && PRE_INSTANTIATION && PARTIAL_SPECIALIZATION_OF_TEMPLATE_MEMBER
  //Unexpected =>
  static_assert(A<int>::B<double>::value==1,"");
#else //Expected =>
  static_assert(A<int>::B<double>::value==2,"");
#endif
```

clang does not consider the partial specialization of `template B`. GCC always considers it. clang has this "unexpected" behavior only if we force `A<int>` instantiation before we declare the partial specialization of `A<T>::B`. clang has the expected behavior if we declare a partial specialization of the specialized primary template `A<int>::B`.

Is clang right? Or is there any undiagnosticed UB here?

---

Notice all clang version since c++11 support have this behavior and all gcc version since c++11 support have the "expected" behavior. [Code here](https://godbolt.org/g/zQEtLN)

Comment: Feels like ill-formed NDR.

Comment: @PasserBy I have just found [this sentence](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.spec#1.sentence-5) in the standard. But I am still unsure because B is a partial specialization of the primary template and not of the primary template specialization.

Comment: @PasserBy Finaly this both an underspecification of the standard and it is reported as a clang bug.

Answer (score 3):

This [core language issue #1755](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1755).

According to the direction followed in the recommendation, the gcc
behavior may be standardized [[N4090]](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4090.pdf):

> For a given instantiated class
>   specialization, a preferred primary member template, partial
>   specialization or full specialization can be explicitly declared

In the current c++ standard it is not standardized, the construction is well formed, but the result is unspecified.

This is reported as [clang's bug #17294](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17294)